# Intel NUC running Ubuntu 16.04 booting hangs for five minutes if LAN cable unplugged

Tags: boot, networking, 16.04, ethernet, intel-nuc

I've an Intel NUC NUC6i5SYH (i5 6th generation) running Ubuntu 16.04.

If I have a LAN cable plugged in, the system boots quickly and the LAN networking works as expected. I can get the wireless to connect to our wifi network, but if I unplug the LAN cable, the wireless network does not work.

If I have the LAN cable unplugged and reboot, the system starts to boot and then hangs for five minutes before completing the boot. After this, the wireless connects to the wifi network and the networking works great (still with the LAN cable unplugged).

Here is a picture:

[image: stalled boot]

Comment: Switch off the wi-fi card if you don't use it.

Comment: If you wait the full 5 minutes it will eventually boot up, I had/have the same issue and do not know the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change "dhcp" to "manual" in `/etc/network/interfaces` for that NIC.

for instance,

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

I got the exactly same output. However, I do believe it is quite normal due to NetworkManager work-flow. NetworkManager try to get the IP address for the LAN cable port with default DHCP setting. If no such kind of service there, you will fail eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Network Connections icon on the taskbar, click on Edit Connections and choose Wired Connection 1. Press the Edit button, go to General tab, and check the *Automatically connect to this network when available* option. Save and go back to the Edit Connections window, choose Wireless Connection 1 and repeat the process. This way you will automatically connect to any of it, whichever may be available.